# Create a function that takes a locker number parameter, and returns the floor number

Tags: javascript

I have a job assignment with a problem like this

There is a building with unlimited floors. Within each floor there are a number of lockers with consecutive locker numbers, in a configuration like this:
Floor. 1 there are 5 lockers, number 1-5
Floor. 2 there are 6 lockers, numbers 6-11
Floor. 3 there are 7 lockers, numbers 12-18
Floor. 4 there are 5 lockers, numbers 19-23
Floor. 5 there are 6 lockers, numbers 24-29
Floor. 6 there are 7 lockers, numbers 30-36
Etc…
Create a function that takes a locker number parameter, and returns the floor number

What's the best code to solve this question? Thank you very much.

I did this code:

```
const Floor= 10;

for (let i = 1; i < lantai + 1; i++) {
    var lokerStart = 0;
    var lokerEnd = 0;
    
  if (i % 3 === 1) {
        lokerStart = i;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 4;
  } else if (i % 3 === 2) {
    lokerStart = 6;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 5;
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    lokerStart = 12;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 6;
  }
  console.log("Floor", i, ", Locker Number", `${lokerStart} - ${lokerEnd}`);
}
```

but it resulted in:

Floor 1 ,Locker Number 1 - 5
Floor 2 ,Locker Number 6 - 11
Floor 3 ,Locker Number 12 - 18
Floor 4 ,Locker Number 4 - 8
Floor 5 ,Locker Number 6 - 11
Floor 6 ,Locker Number 12 - 18
Floor 7 ,Locker Number 7 - 11
Floor 8 ,Locker Number 6 - 11
Floor 9 ,Locker Number 12 - 18
Floor 10 ,Locker Number 10 - 14

I want a function to get a correct floor by inputing locker number 19 for example and get floor 4.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question and where your problem lies can you try and reword it more clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry as english is not my first language. I want a function that can return the floor number and locker number correctly. I want the code resulted in Floor 4 Number 19-23 and Floor 11, Locker Number 37-42 for example but my code is not showing desireable result

Comment: Given that the first number increments but you have code that pins the first number to `6` and `12` in some instance, clearly that's not what you intended and those must be derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question body (your attempted solution) doesn't seem to match your problem: you need to create a function that gets the locker number as the input (argument) and returns the floor.

There's probably a pure mathematical way to do that. Meanwhile, my solution here is a bit more naive, it starts at the first floor and keeps adding lockers according to your rule (`5`, `6`, `7`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `5`...) as we go up the floors (check the `while`), until finding the correct floor:

```js
function getFloor(n) {
  let currentFloor = 1;
  let lockersArray = [5, 6, 7];
  let lockersSoFar = lockersArray[(currentFloor - 1) % 3];
  while (n > lockersSoFar) {
    currentFloor++;
    lockersSoFar += lockersArray[(currentFloor - 1) % 3];
  }
  return currentFloor;
};

console.log(getFloor(4))
console.log(getFloor(18))
console.log(getFloor(19))
console.log(getFloor(42))
console.log(getFloor(128))
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @GerardoFurtado, there is indeed a pure mathematical way to solve this problem (a terser version can be found in the snippet below):

```js
function findFloor(lockerNumber) {
  const quotient = Math.floor(lockerNumber / 18);
  const remainder = lockerNumber % 18;
  
  if (remainder > 11) {
    return quotient * 3 + 3;
  } else if (remainder > 5) {
    return quotient * 3 + 2;
  } else {
    return quotient * 3 + 1;
  }
}
```

### Explanation

First, let's have a look at an ASCII visualization of the building in question:

```
 1 | # # # # #
 2 | # # # # # #
 3 | # # # # # # #

 4 | # # # # #
 5 | # # # # # #
 6 | # # # # # # #

 7 | # # # # #
 8 | # # # # # #
 9 | # # # # # # #

10 | # # # # #
11 | # # # # # #
12 | # # # # # # #

...
```

See how they repeat? Every 3 floors the number of locker goes from 5 through 7 and then it becomes 5 again. Since these blocks are the same, we just need to find how many of them are there. A simple division will do (remember to round it down to the nearest integer). Note that, since this is the number of *blocks*, we need to multiply it by 3 to get the number of corresponding floors.

```js
const quotient = Math.floor(lockerNumber / 18);
```

Now, how to find the rest of them? You probably got it right: the remainder of the division above.

```js
const remainder = lockerNumber % 18;
```

The important part: If the remainder is greater than 11, we have three floors left to climb. If it is greater than 5 but less than or equal to 11, two floors. Else, one floor left. Make sure to add them to our final result.

```js
if (remainder > 11) {
  return quotient * 3 + 3;
} else if (remainder > 5) {
  return quotient * 3 + 2;
} else {
  return quotient * 3 + 1;
}
```

Try it:

```js
function findFloor(lockerNumber) {
  const quotient = Math.floor(lockerNumber / 18);
  const remainder = lockerNumber % 18;
  
  return quotient * 3 + 1 + Math.floor(remainder / 6);
}

for (let i = 1; i < 1e9; i += Math.random() * 1e8 | 0) {
  console.log(i, findFloor(i));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I said that's the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

A few things, firstly, you are resetting your start and end every loop. This is what causes it to drop the values every 3 floors. Secondly, you hardcoded the start values for `i%3==2` and `i%3==0`. This makes it so that your values are always starting from there.

Shift the initialising values outside and use the variables to determine the next start.

```
const lantai= 10;
var lokerStart = 0;
var lokerEnd = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < lantai + 1; i++) {
    
    
  if (i % 3 === 1) {
        lokerStart = lokerEnd + 1;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 4;
  } else if (i % 3 === 2) {
    lokerStart = lokerEnd + 1;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 5;
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    lokerStart = lokerEnd + 1;
        lokerEnd = lokerStart + 6;
  }
  console.log("Floor", i, ", Locker Number", `${lokerStart} - ${lokerEnd}`);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Floor 1 , Locker Number 1 - 5
Floor 2 , Locker Number 6 - 11
Floor 3 , Locker Number 12 - 18
Floor 4 , Locker Number 19 - 23
Floor 5 , Locker Number 24 - 29
Floor 6 , Locker Number 30 - 36
Floor 7 , Locker Number 37 - 41
Floor 8 , Locker Number 42 - 47
Floor 9 , Locker Number 48 - 54
Floor 10 , Locker Number 55 - 59
```